# Appengine errors not appearing in logs

Tags: python, google-app-engine, error-handling

I have the following problem:

I can see some mysterious errors on the Appengine Dashboard but when I go to the logs I can't find any relevant entries. Otherwise the URIs are working fine when I request them.

If I click on the links on the dashboard which take me to the logs with a prefilled regexp filter, the logs are empty.

I only have one guess:
When a request takes longer to load and the user closes the browser window/tab, before the page has been loaded, theese kind of errors are generated but not logged. But I can't prove this assumption. This guess is based on what I see sometimes when developing locally with the SDK.

I use the python SDK. I only have one live version of the app.

Do you maybe have any clues what happens here? Thanks.

Comment: please post screenshots of the error section in app engine dashboard and what you see after clicking any link

Comment: Hi tony, thanks for your comment. It helped me a lot. Just see my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was taking some screenshots as tony asked in the comments, I found the solution.

These errors are all HEAD requests. Since my app doesn't support them, they generate a 405 HTTP response code which is shown on the dashboard as error but then in the logs they don't get the error icon. They just seem to be fine at first sight.